# Rich Snippets Review Aggregate displaying images in search results

Tags: microdata, rich-snippets

I'm trying to get an image to be included within google search results for a review aggregate, and have not had any success.

Based on this page from Google, it should be possible: 
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146645?hl=en&ref_topic=1088474

However, I have been unable to get the Google Structured Data tool to display the image i've specified:

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kidspot.com.au%2Fparenting-directory%2FSkincare%2B247%2FCleanskin-Candle-Company%2B38267%2FNational.htm

There is an image specified for the page, the localbusiness and the review aggregate, but none of these get used.

i'm not sure if the structure of the microdata on the page is wrong, or if it's an issue with using localbusiness object or if google just doesn't want to display images.

Any help would be appreciated

Cheers

Chris

Comment: Why do you think it is possible to get image for Review Rich Snippet? I don't see this option at the link you've provided.

Comment: the first link has 2 sections, Review and Aggregate Reviews. Aggregate Reviews has a "Photo" property.

Comment: True. But screenshots don't show images. And photo is not mandatory property - which means that it's not used in building rich snippet for now. So answer for your question is that Google doesn't show images for these kinds of snippets.

Answer (score 2):

The max image dimensions must be: height 120px and width 100px with max aspect-ratio 3.

[Specify thumbnails](http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1626955)